# AudioKitUI and formatting

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, audiokit

Quite new to Swift and organising UI buttons and sliders programmatically is the least fun I have had so far!
I am using 2 instances of `AKSlider` here and would like to make the Y slider vertical. I'm sure this should be easy enough.

Also if anyone knows a good tutorial for laying out UI controls (sliders, buttons, labels etc) programmatically much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
fileprivate lazy var stack: UIStackView = {
 let sliderOne = AKSlider(property: "Y VELOCITY",
                                   value: yVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped],
                                       range: 0 ... 100,

                                       taper: 4,
                                       format: "%1f Hz"
                      ) { sliderValue in
                          yVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped] = sliderValue

                       ballBloqArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped].physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:  0, dy: (yVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped] * 10))
                      }
    sliderOne.draw(CGRect(width: 60, height: 20))

    let sliderTwo = AKSlider(property: "X VELOCITY",
                                         value: xVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped],
                                             range: 0 ... 100,

                                             taper: 4,
                                             format: "%0.3f Hz"
                            ) { sliderValue in
                                xVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped] = sliderValue

                             ballBloqArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped].physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:  (xVelocityBallArray[ballBloqDoubleTapped] * 10), dy: 0)
                            }
    sliderTwo.draw(CGRect(width: 60, height: 20))

    let hStackNoteButtons = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [sliderOne])
           hStackNoteButtons.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           hStackNoteButtons.axis = .horizontal

    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [sliderOne, sliderTwo, ballIDLabel, MIDIChannelSlider]
    )
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually

    return stack
}()
```

The stack is added to a container view elsewhere which is part of a Pop Up view I have created in a Spritekit game.

**EDIT:** I have kind of managed to do this with the .`transform` . Using `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))`.
But it seems a bit sloppy. And in this instance I end up with half of a slider!